# Как сделать так чтобы 1 панель появлялась только после закрытия 2 или 3 итд

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть меню при нажатии на кнопки которого всплывают панели, я написал скрипт, чтобы
,скажем, 3 панель появлялась только после закрытия открытой 1,2,4 или 5

```
     function close_1() {
    $('#panel2').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel3').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel4').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel5').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel1').fadeIn();
}
function close_2() {
    $('#panel1').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel3').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel4').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel5').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel2').fadeIn();
}
function close_3() {
    $('#panel1').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel2').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel4').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel5').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel3').fadeIn();
}

function close_4() {
    $('#panel1').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel2').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel3').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel5').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel4').fadeIn();
}
function close_5() {
    $('#panel1').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel2').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel3').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel4').fadeOut('fast').delay(1000);
    $('#panel5').fadeIn();
}
```

Но он работает только первый раз сверху вниз т.е. 1->2 всё хорошо 2->3 всё хорошо итд  когда 5->3 появляется 3 и только потом исчезает 5

Вот html код:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                            <li class="active">
                                <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="close_1()" href="#panel1">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="close_2()" href="#panel2">МОЯ ИСТОРИЯ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="close_3()" href="#panel3">КОНСУЛЬТАЦИИ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="close_4()" href="#panel4">НОВОСТИ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a data-toggle="tab" onclick="close_5()" href="#panel5">КОНТАКТЫ</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                         <div class="tab-content">
                           <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <p class="bord3"></p>
                                            2
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                         <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="panel2" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <p class="bord3"></p>
                                            2
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="panel3" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <p class="bord3"></p>
                                            3
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="panel4" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <p class="bord3"></p>
                                            4
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       <div class="tab-content">
                            <div id="panel5" class="tab-pane fade">
                                <div class="container-fluid">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xs-12">
                                            <p class="bord3"></p>
                                            4
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: стоит добавить разметку, а так же не совсем понятно, что именно должно происходить и в каком порядке

Comment: @Grundy при нажатии на пункт меню первым делом должен скрываться активный пункт и появляться нужный

Comment: ага, так понятнее, добавьте пример разметки, и css и я напишу как их поправить

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как активным может быть только один элемент, то не нужно скрывать все, достаточно скрыть этот активный.

У jQuery есть метод [promise](https://api.jquery.com/promise/), который возвращает promise, у которого уже можно использовать метод then.

Таким образом код можно привести к такому:

```js
$('[data-toggle=tab]').click(function() {
  var tab = this.hash,
    li = $(this).parent();

  $('.tab-pane.active').fadeOut('fast')
    .add('.active').add(li).toggleClass('active')
    .delay(500).promise().then(function() {
      li.hasClass('active') && $(tab).addClass('active').fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```css
.fade {
  display: none;
}
li.active {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.fade.in {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
  <li class="active">
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel1">ГЛАВНАЯ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel2">МОЯ ИСТОРИЯ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel3">КОНСУЛЬТАЦИИ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel4">НОВОСТИ</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#panel5">КОНТАКТЫ</a>
  </li>

</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="panel1" class="tab-pane fade in active">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p class="bord3"></p>
          1
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="panel2" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p class="bord3"></p>
          2
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="panel3" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p class="bord3"></p>
          3
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="panel4" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p class="bord3"></p>
          4
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="panel5" class="tab-pane fade">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <p class="bord3"></p>
          5
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```